# Web page not loading on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

I have made a setup which installs a website and it runs perfectly fine when I run it on my own desktop. On button click, the page generates an XML file and saves the data in database. But when I try to run it on other desktops after installing, the page just shows the loading bar and hangs in between.

It's driving me crazy but I still can't figure out the issue!

I have IIS 7.5 installed. My desktop has Windows 7 while the one on which I'm trying to install is XP.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to save the XML File in **C:\**. Is it because of the permissions or something?

Comment: Do you see any errors being logged in the event vwr or iis logs? You should also consider custom logging within your application to troubleshoot.

Comment: what do you mean "But when I try to run it on other desktops after installing"? So you are referring to Desktop application not web application?

Comment: @ryadavilli: Okay. I'll just try that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give "Network Service" a full control. Just follow this steps for Windows 7.

Go to your web app directory where you are wring your XML file. Click Properties go to Security tab.

check if "Network Service" is in the list of Group or usernames. If not click "Edit" click "Add" and on the "Enter object names" box just input "Network" click "Check Names" select "Network Service" from the result then click "Ok". Give full control by highlighting the newly added "Network Service" or Select it then click "Edit". Highlight again the "Network Service" then check the "Full control". Click "Ok". Now test your web app again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for everything!

But my main issue was that C: had some rights issue. So I created a new folder where I stored my XML File and it worked fine after that!